# Preserve editing capabilities on a form with fpdi

Tags: forms, tcpdf, editing, fpdi

Okay here is the problem. I generate a pdf (9 pages) with various data from a form and some calculations. Everything is okay.

But the last page I add is a form with editing capabilities, so you can edit the fields, but I add some dynamic values at the top of the form.

```
// Custom FPDI implementation   
$pdf = new MY_FPDI(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false); 
....

$pdf->AddPage();
$pages = $pdf->setSourceFile( APPPATH.'/../pdf/offer.pdf');
$page = $pdf->ImportPage( 1 );
$pdf->useTemplate( $page, 0, 5 );
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(60, 5, 60, 46, ucfirst($data->company_name), 0, 0, 0, true, 'L', true);
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(100, 5, 60, 52, $data->company_address.', '.$data->company_zip.' '.$data->company_city, 0, 0, 0, true, 'L', true);

$pdf->Output(BASEPATH.'../pdf/'.date('Y').'_EX_'.sprintf("%03s",$data->id).'.pdf', 'FD');
```

Is there a way to preserve the other dynamic fields (blank) so we can fill it directly in the pdf ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, there's [no way](http://www.setasign.com/support/faq/fpdi/after-importing-a-page-all-form-fields-are-gone/#question-206).

> As FPDI does not modify a PDF document but imports it page by page into a structure which can re-used with FPDF, all content outside a pages content stream, like form field annotations, get lost.